# Code::Blocks will not run program

Tags: codeblocks

I run Code::Blocks on Windows 8.1 and this just started happening today.

Whenever I try to run my code for the first time, it compiles and I get the .exe running, but it freezes on a black screen. After waiting a while I close it and try to run it again.

Then it won't compile, says:

```
ld.exe||cannot open output file C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Projects\Trying.exe Permission denied|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Whenever I run it again it just gives this error.
Deleting the files don't help, and the .exe won't delete, Windows gives me an error that it's still running despite nothing showing up on Task Manager.

This only happens with new projects I try to create. Even "Hello World" gets this error. My other older projects run fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like `C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Projects\Trying.exe` is still being executed in the background, thus the write error. Maybe Ctrl-Alt-Del to terminate it, and try building it again?

Comment: Ensure that the debugger is off `Debug -> Stop Debugger`, too?